# Improve performance by using multiple Classifiers instead of one

Tags: machine-learning, vector, classification

Let's say I have Dataset D which can be described as feature vector V
After doing some analysis, I realize that the samples in this dataset are converged to 3 different set of features. I am able to create 3 feature vectors V1, V2, V3 which are (almost) subsets of V, but they describe more precisely D.
In other words, D can be divided into D1, D2, D3 - each of these sub-datasets can be expressed really well by V1, V2, V3.

My question: is that a usual/acceptable approach that I would use 3 features vectors for the training of D1, D2, D3 and then create 3 classifiers **instead** of using only 1 feature vector V to make 1 classifier only?

The kind of "convergence" is also common with samples out of my dataset as well, so I want to use multiple classifiers to generalize them.

Thank you!

Comment: No, if your model is good it should be able to separate these 3 groups without needing you to do it. If you remove all the other "categories" from one model you will be in trouble.

Comment: @user2974951 i think i need to clarify a bit. D1, D2, D3 here are subsets of dataset D, they all contains samples which belong to different classes (I am doing binary classification here)

Thanks for your advice